# Extending Generic Abstract Class: Correct Bounding

Tags: java, generics, abstract

```
public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager<SlotA> mA = new Manager<SlotA>();
    }

}

class Manager<SlotClass extends Slot> {

}

abstract class Slot {
    public Slot(Manager<? extends Slot> m) {

    }
}

class SlotA extends Slot {

    public SlotA(Manager<SlotB> m) { //a constructor with Manager<SlotA> is not required!
        super(m);
    }
}

class SlotB extends Slot {

    public SlotB(Manager<SlotA> m) { //a constructor with Manager<SlotB> is not required!
        super(m);
    }

}
```

Above is code that models a problem I am trying to overcome. My goal is to enforce that subclasses of `Slot` **must** have a constructor with a Manager using the same generic type. That is to say, `SlotC` must have a constructor `SlotC(Manager<SlotC> m)`. As can be seen above, `SlotA` and `SlotB` do not require a `SlotA(Manager<SlotA>)` and `SlotB(Manager<SlotB>)`respectively.

I know that the constructor of the abstract `Slot` does not meet this requirement. How can I edit the above code to achieve this?

**Edit:**

I know that I can add a generic parameter `T` to `Slot` and make the constructor `Slot<T>(Manager<T>)` but that means requiring `SlotA<SlotA>` and that `SlotA<SlotB>` is possible. Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to make `Slot` class generic, using self-referential type parameter:

```
abstract class Slot<T extends Slot<T>> {
    public Slot(Manager<T> m) {

    }
}

class SlotA extends Slot<SlotA> {

    public SlotA(Manager<SlotA> m) { //a constructor with Manager<SlotA> is not required!
        super(m);
    }
}

class SlotB extends Slot<SlotB> {

    public SlotB(Manager<SlotB> m) { //a constructor with Manager<SlotB> is not required!
        super(m);
    }
}
```

Now your `SlotA` constructor can only have a `Manager<SlotA>`.

However, this doesn't restrict someone from creating a class like:

```
class SlotC extends Slot<SlotA> { }
```

And there is no way you can avoid that. This is one such area, where Java generics fails to apply restriction at compile time.

Comment: Just an additional note: that is the reason why inheritance is not allowed in the most prominent example where this is used: enum - which is always final.

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for the additional information. This is the solution. However, this requires changes to be made to `class Manager<SlotClass extends Slot>`, however. Is `class Manager<SlotClass extends Slot<?>>` the correct fix for this? Or does it open any other generic issues?

Comment: Change it to `Manager<T extends Slot<T>>`.